# I don't understand why my runnable jar will not start

Tags: java, manifest, executable-jar

Ok, Let me know if I am not providing enough info. When I export the runnable jar file I chose "Package required libraries into generate JAR.

Here is my cmd output from when I try to run it:

```
java -jar CLA_Sync_Test.jar
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tools\test\test.xml (The system cannot find the
file specified)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.Project.ameier.XMLparser.<init>(XMLparser.java:32)
        at com.Project.ameier.Main.<init>(Main.java:146)
        at com.Project.ameier.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:63)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.Intel.ameier.Main.<init>(Main.java:158)
        at com.Intel.ameier.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:63)
        ... 3 more
```

If this is a manifest issue...how can I setup eclipse to prevent this in the future?

Comment: so ... mentioned is file really there? is it accessible?

Comment: If you edit your question, the revision history is still available. That wasn't even worth editing out.

Comment: I put the file there, it works fine. *puts head down in shame

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty self explanatory:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tools\test\test.xml (The system cannot find the
>   file specified)

It can't find the file at `C:\Tools\test\test.xml`.

Comment: your answer [lacks this picture](http://img3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20070526081820/uncyclopedia/images/1/15/CaptainobviousChooseOption.jpg) :-)

Comment: wow im an idiot. sorry...busy at work and too distracted to read. my fault. i deserve the downvotes

Comment: @Ducksauce88 I am facing the same issue as you but i never had any test.xml file with me. would you be able to tell me what should I do